# Number of arguments in operator overload in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm learning C++ and I created two simple hello-world applications. In both of them I use operator overload, but here is the problem. On the first one, I can provide two arguments to overload operator, and it's fine.

*Header:*

```
enum Element {a,b,c,d,e};
Element operator + (Element x, Element y);
//more overloads for -, *, / here
```

*Source:*

```
Element operator + (Element x, Element y) {
    return ArrayOfElements[x][y];
}
```

But in my second app (simple complex number calculator) - this method didn't work. After googling and figuring out why, I end up with this code:

*Header:*

```
struct Complex {
        double Re;
        double Im;

        Complex (double R, double I) : Re(R), Im(I) { }

        Complex operator + (Complex &Number);
        //more overloads
    };
```

*Source:*

```
Complex Complex::operator + (Complex &Number)
    {
        Complex tmp = Complex(0, 0);
        tmp.Re = Re + Number.Re;
        tmp.Im = Im + Number.Im;
        return tmp;
    }
```

**It's working now, but I want to know, why in the first piece of code I was allowed to put two arguments in `operator` overloading, but with the second one I was given the following error?**

```
complex.cpp:5:51: error: 'Complex Complex::operator+(Complex, Complex)' must take either zero or one argument
```

It's the same whenever I use classes or not. I've been seeking through many docs and the second way seem to be more correct. Maybe it's because of different argument types?

Both sources compiled with `-Wall -pedantic` parameters using `g++`, both are using the same libraries.

Comment: Member functions have an implicit `this` argument

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Suppose you have a class like this:

```
class Element {
public:
    Element(int value) : value(value) {}
    int getValue() const { return value; }
private:
    int value;
};
```

There are four ways to define a binary operator such as `+`.

1. As a free function with access to only the `public` members of the class:

   ```
   // Left operand is 'a'; right is 'b'.
   Element operator+(const Element& a, const Element& b) {
       return Element(a.getValue() + b.getValue());
   }
   ```

   `e1 + e2 == operator+(e1, e2)`
2. As a member function, with access to all members of the class:

   ```
   class Element {
   public:
       // Left operand is 'this'; right is 'other'.
       Element operator+(const Element& other) const {
           return Element(value + other.value);
       }
       // ...
   };
   ```

   `e1 + e2 == e1.operator+(e2)`
3. As a `friend` function, with access to all members of the class:

   ```
   class Element {
   public:
       // Left operand is 'a'; right is 'b'.
       friend Element operator+(const Element& a, const Element& b) {
           return a.value + b.value;
       }
       // ...
   };
   ```

   `e1 + e2 == operator+(e1, e2)`
4. As a `friend` function defined outside the class body—identical in behaviour to #3:

   ```
   class Element {
   public:
       friend Element operator+(const Element&, const Element&);
       // ...
   };

   Element operator+(const Element& a, const Element& b) {
       return a.value + b.value;
   }
   ```

   `e1 + e2 == operator+(e1, e2)`

Comment: If it's a member function, you can do `Element(2) + 3` but not `2 + Element(3)`.

Comment: I don't have any classes in the first one (just in the second one), but thanks for the great answer!

Comment: can you add who will be the callers of these respective function?

Answer (score 8):

If you prefer that `operator+` takes both operands as explicit arguments, it must be defined as a free (i.e. non-member) function:

```
class Complex {
    friend Complex operator+(const Complex& lhs, const Complex& rhs);
}

Complex operator+(const Complex& lhs, const Complex& rhs) {
    ...
}
```

You *have* to use this form if the left operand is of a primitive type, or of a class that you don't control (and thus can't add a member function to).

Comment: ... and you should use this form if there might be any implicit conversions to `Complex`.

Answer (score 7):

Since + is a binary operator, if you overload it inside a struct/class, you can only provide one more operand, the reason is that the first operand is implicitly the calling object. That is why in the first case, you have two parameters since it is outside scope of your class/struct, while in the second case, it was overloaded as member function.

Answer (score 1):

If overloaded function is a member function to the class, the we pass only one argument, and there is one hidden parameter (*this* pointer) that points to other object required to perform binary operation like '+'. *this* pointer points to one of the operands and calls the overloaded function; while other operand is passed as an argument.
Example:

```
class ExampleClass
{
public:
   int x;
   //a this pointer will be passed to this function
   ExampleClass& operator+(const ExampleClass& o){ return x+o.x; }
};



ExampleClass obj1, obj2, obj;
obj = obj1 + obj2; //the overloaded function is called as obj1.operator+(obj2) internally
                  //this pointer is passed to the function
```

When the overloaded function is not a member function (either a free function or a friend function), then we don't have the *this* pointer provided to the overloaded function. In this case, the compiler expects two arguments to the function which are used as operands.

```
class ExampleClass
{
    public:
       int x;
       //this pointer will not be passed to this function
       friend ExampleClass& operator+(const ExampleClass& o1, const ExampleClass& o2){ return o1.x+o2.x; }
};



obj = obj1 + obj2; //the overloaded function is called as operator+(obj1, obj2) internally
```

Answer (score 1):

e1 + e2 == e1.operator+(e2) this means e1 is a object and operator+ is a member and e2 is as a variable .basicaly oops permits us to do just write e1 + e2 compiler automatically  understand as a e1.operator+(e1)